# Python Pywinrm using powershell to control the AD of remote windows, returns Different results from the local end

Tags: python, powershell, active-directory, winrm

When I use pywinrm to remote windows (AD server), session returns inconsistent results, as follows.

```
import winrm
host = 'XXXX'
domain = 'XXXX'
user = 'XXXX'
password = 'XXXX'
session = winrm.Session(host , auth=('{}@{}'.format(user,domain), password), transport='ntlm',
                        server_cert_validation='ignore')

ps_script1 = """Get-Acl"""
ps_script2 = """Import-Module ActiveDirectory"""
ps_script3 = """Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Get-ADUser -Filter 'Name -like "XXXX"'......'"""

result1 = session.run_ps(ps_script1)
result2 = session.run_ps(ps_script2)
result3 = session.run_ps(ps_script3)
```

In result1, it works well and returns "correct result". But in result2, its return is "Error initializing"

Also in result3, its return """
Unable to contact the server. This may be because this server does not exist, it is currently down, or it does not have the Active Directory Web Services running.'.Get-ADUser : Unable to contact the server. This may be because this server
does not exist, it is currently down, or it does not have the Active Directory """

But all powershell command works well when I log in windows directly.

Answer (score 0):

I add Credential and resolve this question.

```
ps_script = """[string]$userName = '"""+winuser+"""'
               [string]$userPassword = '"""+password+"""'
               [SecureString]$secureString = $userPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
               [PSCredential]$credentialObejct = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $userName, $secureString


               [your PS code] -Properties * -credential $credentialObejct)"""
```